# Problem with my clamp macro

Tags: c++, macros, clamp

I have a problem with my clamp macro, when when my value is over 10 and my high is over 17 it stops working.  Any idea?

```
#define CLAMP(value, low, high) (((value)<(low))?(low):(((value)>(high))?(high):(value)))
```

Comment: The first thing to do when debugging a macro is to expand it and see why you are getting the incorrect results.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would suggest using a safer way than a macro:

```
template <typename T> T CLAMP(const T& value, const T& low, const T& high) 
{
  return value < low ? low : (value > high ? high : value); 
}
```

Comment: +1, but I suggest `template <typename V, typename L, typename H>`

Comment: @Beta: This way it will catch potentially dangerous typecasts. But your approach would work, too.

Comment: There's little reason to pack the if-else-statement like that, in a template function. +1 otherwise (personally I wouldn't name a function all uppercase just because it replaces a macro in functionality).

Comment: This is the nicest answer so far. Nit: All uppercase names should be reserved for macros. Cheers,

Comment: @Beta: The standard `std::max()` uses a single type, instead of the three you propose. At some point in time Alexandrescu wrote the perfect *correct* typesafe version of the C macro `#define MAX( x, y ) ((x)>(y)? (x) : (y))` in "only" 174 lines of code. The standard committee decided that the problems that the `std::min` template has (requires the two arguments to the same type, fails if the arguments are of different types) were not worth the changes that Alexandrescu proposal required. Sometimes the simple approach is good enough.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Clamp doesn't have the difficulties that min and max face, because there's a natural choice for the return type: V. There may still be some complications, but it wouldn't be anywhere near as painful as min/max.

Comment: @MarceloCantos: *and*? Note that the comment is addressed to Beta (read his comment, where he suggests using three separate types for the bounds and the value. As you already mentioned that does not apply to this case, and even if it did (as is the case of `std::min`/`std::max`), providing multiple types becomes problematic quite soon. I think we agree that using 3 different types is *not* the way, right?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: I understood who the comment was addressed to, and I don't automatically agree. `clamp<V,L,H>()` has the same motivations as `max<A,B>()`. The min/max solution was, I suspect, complex because of the need to infer return types. `clamp()`, doesn't have that problem. You can declare it as `V clamp(V v, L l, H h)`. I normally define clamp thus and it hasn't caused me any problems. I confess that I haven't studied this in any great depth, so perhaps there are problems that I haven't foreseen.

Comment: I am aware of the edge-case that `clamp(4, 1.5, 3.5)` returns 3, but to me that simply requires an understanding of the chosen semantics — a clamped int is still an int — plus a reminder-to-self, "Don't do that."

Comment: @MarceloCantos: Ok, I understand what you are saying now. I would still provide only a single type, but that could be personal preference :)

Comment: in C++17 just use [std::clamp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25932021/995714)

Answer (score 4):

Your macro is fine.  If you pass in a `high` that is less than `low`, you'll see strange results, but that's unlikely to be the cause.

The most likely result is that you're passing in an expression that has side effects, such as using the `++` operator or calling a function.  If you have an expression that has side effects, then because of the way that macro substitution works, the side effects could happen multiple times.  For example:

```
CLAMP(x++, low, high)  // expands to:
(x++ < low) ? low : ((x++ > high) ? high : x++);
```

`x++` gets evaluated multiple times, which is definitely not what you want (it's undefined behavior, due to the lack of a sequence point).

I'd suggest rewriting the macro as a template:

```
template <typename T> T CLAMP(T value, T low, T high)
{
    return (value < low) ? low : ((value > high) ? high : value);
}
```

Comment: why even keep the trinary operator?  Why not rewrite it with two `if` statements and three `return`?

Answer (score 3):

Using a template function as already suggested is a better solution.

Anyway, if you're having this kind of problem (both with a macro or a function) you should simplify your expression; look at this pseudocode:

```
max(a,b): a>b ? a : b
min(a,b): a<b ? a : b
clamp(x,lo,hi): min( hi, max(lo,x) )
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also make it an `inline` function so it will be like a macro but safer.