# Most efficient/elegant way to clip a number?

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, logic

Given a real (n), a maximum value this real can be (upper), and a minimum value this real can be (lower), how can we most efficiently clip n, such that it remains between lower and upper?

Of course, using a bunch of if statements can do this, but that's boring! What about more compact and elegant/fun solutions?

My own quick attempt (C/C++):

```
float clip( float n, float lower, float upper )
{
    n = ( n > lower ) * n + !( n > lower ) * lower;
    return ( n < upper ) * n + !( n < upper ) * upper;
}
```

I'm sure there are other, better ways to do this, that's why I'm putting this out there..!

Comment: "cap" usually refers only to an upper limit. The word you want is "clip".

Comment: I doubt about efficiency, but your solution really is not readable. Why don't you just define a some kind of "clamp" function and use that.

Comment: Also read this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/427477/fastest-way-to-clamp-a-real-fixed-floating-point-value

Comment: Hmm did a search and missed that :/ Must have been because I was originally using the term cap, not clip/clamp. Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370474/is-there-a-function-in-c-or-c-to-do-saturation-on-an-integer

Comment: The thing that truly baffles me is: what lead you to the complicated bool trickery with 4 `*` operations in place of the more natural `if (n<lower) return lower; if (n>upper) return upper; return n;`?  (This firmly reinforces my belief that _programmers are often their own worst enemy when it comes to taking the trivial and making it extremely complicated._)

Comment: I think you're missing the point of the question - note that I say "Of course, using a bunch of if statements can do this, but that's boring!". This was a question to dig at possible alternatives to that method. I'm certainly not suggesting that my solution up there is the best, that's for sure!

Comment: Ok. I took the phrase "bunch of if statements" too literally; I don't consider 2 to be a bunch, and figured you were overcomplicating the if logic to the point where you started contemplating the truly weird. Of course you could always condense 2 ifs into 2 ternaries: `return (n<lower) ? lower : (n>higher) ? higher : n;` (Personally I don't really like code golf though and put far more weight on easily readable and maintainable.)

Comment: Readability and simplicity is why I selected the answer by @justin :)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, it's not like comparison operators perform better than an if check?

Comment: related [fastest-way-to-clamp-a-real-fixed-floating-point-value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/427477/52074)

Answer (score 106, accepted):

What about boring, old, readable, and shortest yet:

```
float clip(float n, float lower, float upper) {
  return std::max(lower, std::min(n, upper));
}
```

?

This expression could also be 'genericized' like so:

```
template <typename T>
T clip(const T& n, const T& lower, const T& upper) {
  return std::max(lower, std::min(n, upper));
}
```

**Update**

Billy ONeal added:

> Note that on windows you might have to define NOMINMAX because they define min and max macros which conflict

Comment: +1 -- good enough that I deleted my answer. Note that on windows you might have to define `NOMINMAX` because they define min and max macros which conflict :(

Comment: This belongs in the standard. C++1z, anyone?

Comment: @jbruni o hay: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4536.html

Comment: @underscore_d Thanks for the update. I hope it gets approved.

Comment: Would the following be a correct implementation? https://pastebin.com/m3yVJCsx I saw this in a library I am using and the comparison seems wrong at least for using floats in this 'genericized'  version?

Comment: @BillyONeal – _(and for others to know too)_ – There's another way to prevent this conflict from happening. Just add a set of `()` around the functions call. That is, writing it like that `return (std::max)(lower, (std::min)(n, upper));` will solve the issue without having to define `NOMINMAX`...

Answer (score 72):

Why rewrite something that's [already been written for you](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/algorithm/doc/html/algorithm/Misc.html#the_boost_algorithm_library.Misc.clamp)?

```
#include <boost/algorithm/clamp.hpp>
boost::algorithm::clamp(n, lower, upper);
```

As of C++17, this is now [part of the STL](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/clamp):

```
#include <algorithm>
std::clamp(n, lower, upper);
```

Comment: standard answer: because not everyone is willing/allowed/physically able to pull in Boost. However, this implementation was suggested for migration to the stdlib, dunno the current status though.

Comment: Looks like it will be standard in C++17: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/clamp

Comment: `clamp` part of Swift standard library too

Comment: @underscore_d don't worry it's part of C++17. until then you can continue constantly reinventing the wheel and avoid using good peer-reviewed portable code.

Comment: @TrevorBoydSmith I don't have anything against Boost, and your rather contrived evangelism for it is not needed. That said, it looks like I wasn't wrong in assessing the usual reasons that people don't just do what you want them to do and use Boost, and it's surprisingly not because they just want to annoy you by "avoid[ing] using good peer-reviewed portable code". I also don't see why you edited this existing answer to be completely different when (A) you could've posted your own but also (B) other people already had, but OK.

Comment: That's a header only library, correct me if I'm wrong, so essentially it is not a big problem because we don't need to compile.

Comment: Adding the entire boost lib for 1 line of code seems a bit overkill.

Comment: @MarcDirven you're not adding "the whole boost lib", you're including one header - only the functionality you are using is compiled in, there is no bloat.

Comment: @Riot Still, installing/downloading a library for such a trivial thing still seems overkill to me imo.

Answer (score 26):

C++17 is expected to add a [clamp](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/clamp) function.  Courtesy of cppreference.com:

```
template<class T>
constexpr const T& clamp( const T& v, const T& lo, const T& hi );

template<class T, class Compare>
constexpr const T& clamp( const T& v, const T& lo, const T& hi, Compare comp );
```

Answer (score 25):

**UPDATE**: C++17's [`<algorithm>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/algorithm) header added [`std::clamp(value, low, high)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/clamp).

In older C++ versions, I'd very rarely go beyond...

```
return n <= lower ? lower : n >= upper ? upper : n;
```

...or, if you find it more readable keeping the left-to-right ordering of lower, n and upper...

```
return n <= lower ? lower : n <= upper ? n : upper;
...or...
return lower >= n ? lower : n <= upper ? n : upper;
```

(using `<=`, `>=` is faster than `<`, `>` because when the terms are equal it avoids further comparisons)

If you know you might have them, you'd want to check if NaN / Inf etc. are preserved....

I say rarely and not never just because sometimes less branching can be faster, but if you or other people you work with are likely to find the code for that cryptic, it's best avoided unless it's in performance-critical code and profiling shows it matters.

Comment: "<=, >= is faster than <, >" - probably not. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12135518/is-faster-than

Comment: @kylefinn that link addresses a different question, comparing e.g. a <= 4 to a < 5; in that situation, the branching wanted is the same, and they're just different ways of expressing the condition.  In this situation, I'm talking about branching differently to avoid an extra comparison.

Comment: Oh I think I get it now. In only the case where n==lower, you get away with 1 comp instead of 2.

Answer (score 10):

the best is clearly

```
template <typename t>
t clamp2(t x, t min, t max)
{
if (x < min) x = min;
if (x > max) x = max;
return x;
}
```

as it compiles to

```
movss   xmm0, cs:__real@c2c80000
maxss   xmm0, [rsp+38h+var_18]
movss   xmm1, cs:__real@42c80000
minss   xmm1, xmm0
movss   [rsp+38h+var_18], xmm1
```

it has 0 branches and should be the fastest of all posted above.

also msvc141 with the standard release settings

Comment: simple if-statements are underrated. easy to read, and often easy to optimize away.

Answer (score 6):

Inelegant, unsafe, costly but branchless:

```
n= 0.5 * (n + lower + fabs(n - lower));
n= 0.5 * (n + upper - fabs(upper - n));
```

Comment: This is my favourite for sheer obtuseness; but fabs() may contain branches depending on your library.  To be *REALLY* branchless you could substitute `fabs(x)` with `(x * (1 + (x < 0) * -2)`

Comment: That assumes that the evaluation of `x < 0` is really done branchless. What about extracting the sign bit (msb) from the floating-point representation, cleanly documenting the non-portability? :-)

Answer (score 5):

You might like the ternary operator:

```
value = value<lower?lower:value;
value = value>upper?upper:value;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
n = n + ((n < lower) * (lower - n)) + ((n > upper) * (upper - n));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to use xtensor, it would support multi-dimensional arrays and the solution would be very elegant.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "xtensor/xarray.hpp"
#include "xtensor/xio.hpp"
#include "xtensor/xview.hpp"
#include "xtensor/xrandom.hpp"
xt::xarray<float> ar({2.1, 2.9, -2.1, -2.9});
std::cout<<xt::cast<int>(xt::trunc(ar))<<std::endl;
```

//Answer is { 2, 2, -2, -2 }

Answer (score 0):

The following header file should work for C and C++. Note that it undefines min and max if the macros are already defined:

```
#pragma once

#ifdef min
#undef min
#endif

#ifdef max
#undef max
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
#include <algorithm>

template <typename T>
T clip(T in, T low, T high)
{
    return std::min(std::max(in, low), high);
}
#else /* !__cplusplus */
#define min(a, b) (((a) < (b)) ? (a) : (b))
#define max(a, b) (((a) < (b)) ? (b) : (a))
#define clip(a, b, c) min(max((a), (b)), (c))
#endif /* __cplusplus */
```

Comment: why the f*** MS defined its own MIN MAX, and why the heck something like clamping a value is not in the C++ standard library?

Comment: @DarioOO Replying a bit late, but std::clamp() is available since C++17

Comment: it was about the time! XD

Comment: use [`#define NOMINMAX`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13416418/995714) instead of `#undef`ing them