# Any builtin clamp method in the C++ library?

Tags: c++, std, clamp

I would like to know if there is some builtin clamp method which can clamp a value between a range, say between (0,1)?

```
clamp(a) = a if a is in (0,1)
a < 0 a = 0
a > 1 a = 1
```

Comment: Not that I know of, but it's one `std::max` and one `std::min` call.

Answer (score 6):

C++17 introduced [`std::clamp()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/clamp). Now you don't need to implement your own. Just use `std::clamp(a, 0.0, 1.0)`

If you don't have C++17 but boost is an option then use [`boost::algorithm::clamp(n, lower, upper);`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/algorithm/doc/html/algorithm/Misc.html#the_boost_algorithm_library.Misc.clamp)

Related:

- [What are the new features in C++17?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38060436/995714)
- [Most efficient/elegant way to clip a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9323903/995714)
- [Limit integer to bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41535581/995714)

Answer (score 1):

C++ has no built in clamp function. You can either implement your own, or if you happen to be using [boost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boost_%28C++_libraries%29) it has a [clamp function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/boost/algorithm/clamp.hpp).