# Limit integer to bounds

Tags: c++, max, min, clamp

I'm trying to make sure that `int x` is greater or equal than 0 but smaller than 1080 (screen size in this case).

I came up with this

```
int x = 123;
x = std::min(std::max(x, 0), 1080);
```

This seems ugly. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Looks fine to me. Write a wapper function... http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/algorithm/doc/html/algorithm/Misc.html

Comment: Do it explicitly `if (x >= 0 && x < 1080) { // your code here. }`

Comment: I would take the code to assure the range, and wrap it up in a template, something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3181826/179910).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you live in the future, you can use [`std::clamp` from C++17](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/clamp):

```
x = std::clamp(x, 0, 1080);
```

Comment: Plus one from the future! There is no harm in including good snippets from future standards.

Comment: Ok thanks, this is mostly what I was looking for. I'll keep the min / max combo until future comes

Comment: @Eric: huh?? Just write your own wrapper then replace it with clamp when the time comes...

Answer (score 2):

Naive solution looks ok too:

```
int x = 123;
if (x < 0)
    x = 0;
if (x > 1080)
    x = 1080;
```

or wrap everything in a function:

```
template<typename T>
T between(const T x, const T min, const T max){
   if (x < min)
       return min;

   if (x > max)
       return max;

   return x;
}

int x = between(123, 0, 1080);
```

Comment: code fixed, sorry

Comment: Reasonably simple to write and ultra simple to read... When questions are really simple no need for super complex C++17 things. My prefered way!

Answer (score 1):

Use an unsigned as the type for x. That automatically constrains it to be non-negative.

Then you're left with just the call to std::min which is palatable to me at least.

Building a class that takes an int on construction and has a conversion operator to int is also plausible but requires a fair bit of boilerplate.

Comment: This is a good idea, but unfortunately x is fetched through an API callback so I can't change the type easily. Of course I could cast int to unsigned int, but this is ugly as well imo

Answer (score -1):

Why not just do something like this?

```
int x = 123; /* Or some arbitrary number */
bool bIsInRange = (x >= 0) && (x < 1080);
if(!bIsInRange){
   std::cout << "Variable 'x' is not between 0 and 1080." << std::endl;
   return 1;
} // else, x is fine. Continue operations as normal.
```

Comment: That looks super ugly.

Comment: @melpomene, however, it is also standard, readable, and extremely understandable for anyone of any experience level. Plus, doing it in this normal way does not require additional calls to functions such as `min`, `max`, or `clamp`, which only serve to add overhead/expense to what would otherwise be a simple and essentially weightless task. That being said, I will agree that it is by no means *"beautiful."*

Comment: I don't find it readable. The main issue is the `bIsInRange` variable, which serves no purpose and has a horrible name. As for overhead, I'd expect the compiler to inline min/max/clamp. (And if we're talking efficiency, that `cout << "..." << endl` construct is probably 100 times slower than a plain function call.)