# Convert values to values inside a range in c++ , optimized using boost or std

Tags: c++, optimization, boost, std

I want to validate all the elemnent of an array. If an element is under a value, swap by a min value and if it is above a value, swap by a max value.

But I don´t know how I can do it optimized. For do it I go above all elements, element by element but it is not optimized, and it spend a lot of cpu time in very large arrays.

This is an example of my code:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <math.h>
const int MAX = 10;
int main ()
{
    float minVal = 2.0;
    float maxVal = 11.0;

    float vElem[] = {-111111.0/0.0, 10.0, 90.0, 8.0, -7.0,
                    -0.6, 5.0, 4.0, 33.0, 222222222.0/0};

    for(int i=0; i<MAX; i++){
            if(isinf(vElem[i])==-1 || vElem[i]<minVal) vElem[i] = minVal;
            if(isinf(vElem[i])==1 || vElem[i]>maxVal || isnan(vElem[i])) vElem[i] = maxVal;

            std::cout << vElem[i]<< std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any other options... you must check each one of the elements and decide what to do according to your logic. even if there is a fancy C++ construct, it will underline do the same (iterate over all elements and perform the check operations on it)

Comment: You can use Auto-Parallelization using OpenMP or something if you have multiple cores. Include the header and put `#pragma omp parallel for` above the loop

Comment: What version of C++ do you have access to ? (ie, is C++11 okay ?)

Comment: Is I/O actually necessary to your use case ? Because I/O overhead trumps *everything* you are doing in your loop.

Comment: I have g++ version 4.1.2. The initial input is not necessary

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Most efficient/elegant way to clip a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9323903/most-efficient-elegant-way-to-clip-a-number)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think using elaborate constructs would buy you much here. Maybe making your code a bit cleaner ?

```
std::for_each(std::begin(vElem), std::end(vElem), [](float &val) {
    val = clamp(val, minVal, maxVal);
});
```

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9324012/2567683) is what a typicall clamp function returns

Comment: You say that “elaborate constructs would [not] buy you much” and yet your code is *vastly* cleaner than OP’s (although `std::transform` would be more appropriate than `std::for_each`).

Comment: @KonradRudolph Yes, I was reffering to usage of filtered boost ranges etc. didn't use `transform` to avoid specifying a `result` iterator; I agree it would communicate intentions clearly

Comment: The `result` iterator is just `std::begin(vElem)`: `std::transform` can work in-place.

Comment: Its a good idea, if it couldn`t be optimize. I have g++ version 4.1.2, so I couldn`t use it, but I have rewrite it using your adviced. I have used for_each and although I haven`t installed this package of boost in my project, I have used std::min( std::max( val, minVal ), maxVal ) and is more clearly

Comment: @user3480234 Update your GCC, it’s *woefully* outdated.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Yes, obviously, I meant literally, didn't want to write `std::begin(vElem)` once more; QuickQ : Would you recommend any specific tools in **your** range library that would help for more elegant code in this specific case?

Answer (score 0):

```
  for(int i=0; i<MAX; i++){
      float c = vElem[i];

      //Could convert c to an integer here, so the below uses integer operations
      //Additional cost is two multiplications (scaling up and scaling back down).

      float n = c + ((c < min) * (min - c)) + ((c > max) * (max - c));
      std::cout << n << std::endl;
  }
```

- Two multiplications
- Four additions
- Two comparisons

I think this is faster than any of the `clamp()` implementations referred to in the other answer.

Comment: The floating point operations (the four additions, the two multiplications, and even the two comparisons) are costly, compared to operations on integral types. The `clamp()` function is only two comparisons, conditional jumps. My guess is that the `clamp()` function is faster. Anyway, one cannot know without a bench.

Comment: The linked-to answer is: return n <= lower ? lower : n >= upper ? upper : n; which is ternary operator, which means conditional branches. If you never had to branch- might be faster, but if you did the performance cost would be significant.

Comment: and you could convert the floats to integers at the beginning, use integer arithmetic and then scale the integer back to a float.