# Standard library version of clip function

Tags: c++, c++17

I have wrote a utility named `nostd::clip` that clips a provided value `x` between a `floor` and a `ceiling`:

```
namespace nostd {
    template<class T>
    auto clip(T floor, T x, T ceiling) -> T
    {
        return std::min(ceiling, std::max(floor, x));
    }
}
```

Is there some function in `std` that does the same thing, that I could replace this with? Maybe in C++17?

Comment: You could just go through the list of utilities in the library? Wouldn't take more than a few minutes? And then you'd find out what else is there, too. Nobody studies any more :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want [std::clamp](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/clamp). It does what your custom implementation does.

You really should familiarise yourself with what the standard library provides. A reference site like [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/) is great for that.

Answer (score 5):

Are you looking for [std::clamp](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/clamp)?
More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9323903/most-efficient-elegant-way-to-clip-a-number).