# Is this a good way to use macros?

Tags: c++, objective-c, language-agnostic, macros, styles

I'm aware of the [pitfalls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4100657/problem-with-my-clamp-macro) of macros and avoid them when what I really want is a function.

What I've found them helpful for, though, is storing things like "magic" numbers, file names, font names and so on. So things like:

```
ProjectHeader.h

#ifndef __PROJECT_HEADER__
#define __PROJECT_HEADER__

#define kXMLFileName "scoresAndSettings.xml"

#define AUDIO_DATA_TYPE_FORMAT SInt16
#define NUM_AUDIO_BUFFERS 3
#define AUDIO_SAMPLE_RATE 44100.
#define NUM_AUDIO_CHANNELS 2

#define kGameFont @"Helvetica-Bold"
#define kGameFontSizeNormal 18
#define kGameFontSizeSmall 16
#define kGameFontSizeTiny 11
```

These let me (a) store UI specifics in one place where I can change them and know the change will propagate throughout the code, (b) give them a name that describes their function in the code, and (c) use code autocompletion to know that I've actually typed the right term.

I feel fairly confident that this isn't a terrible way to work, but I'd like to know if someone thinks it is, and if so how to do it better.

These are perhaps a little dodgier but I still find them very helpful:

```
#define __COPY_PROTECTION__
#define __SHOW_FPS__ NO
#define __SKIP_LAUNCH_SCREEN__ 0
#define __START_IN_GAMEPLAY__ 1
#define __START_IN_PREFS__ 0
#define __START_IN_WIN_SCENE__ 0
#define __AUTO_WIN_TESTING__ 0
```

(In various points, then, in the code:

```
AppDelegate.h
if (__START_IN_GAMEPLAY__) {
 [self show:MyGameplay];
 return;
}
[self show:MainScreen];
```

). This allows me to jump straight into testing whatever part of the project I'm working on, by manipulating only macros `#define`d in the `ProjectHeader.h` file.

Is this good? Bad? Is there a better way for next time?

Comment: (This is an Objective-C++ project, by the way, but I think conceptually the question is fairly language-agnostic.)

Comment: @Adam Obj-C++ is a thing. It's a wild and messy thing, but it's also been described as "ridiculously powerful". I will probably keep using it until someone pays me to stop...

Comment: I give up. But your post seems to be a duplicate of this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653839/what-are-c-macros-useful-for

Comment: Why don't you use `const`s and `typedef`s instead? Also, those names with the two underscores are reserved.

Comment: @Pubby ah, didn't know about the underscores, thanks.

Comment: @Pubby yes, the `const`/`typedef` approach is a good one. Does it compile faster / run smaller than #define? Or is it more emblematic of better coding practice generally?

Comment: @buildsucceeded it will likely compile equally fast. albeit the processing is done in different compilation stages. However, the const/typedef approach is typesafe, macro's are not. There are also some benefits for debugging (a const has a name).

Comment: @buildsucceeded The compilation speed is irrelevant when talking about best practices, but you shouldn't notice a change. The execution speed should be identical. It's stupid to use macros when you have perfectly good language features that provide the same functionality but with type-safety and actual symbols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there's nothing in your first set of of macros that wouldn't
better be done with `const` variables, at least in C++:

```
char const kXMLFileName[] = "socresAndSettings.xml";
typedef SInt16 audioDataTypeFormat;
int const numAudioBuffers = 3;
//  ...
```

The advantage of using `const` instead of macros is that the names will
obey scope; for numeric values, there's also the advantage that you can
more easily specify the type (if it's not `int`).  In case of misuse,
the error messages are also generally more understandable.

For your second block, it's harder to say (but the names you've chosen
result in undefined behavior).  My impression is that these are to be
used for conditional compliation.  If so, then they must be macros.  But
in general, conditional compilation is something to be avoided, unless
your goal is obfuscation.

This is not to say that you should never use macros.  There's no other
way to get automatic insertion of `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` in logging
primitives, for example.  I've also used them extensively when
interfacing to Python, or other languages which define a C API: in the C
API, "overloading" is done by manual name mangling, and token pasting in
the macros is about the only easy way to achieve this.

Comment: Excellent answer, thanks! (Can you explain why the names result in undefined behavior though?)

Comment: @buildsucceeded Because the standard says so:-) (§17.4.3.1.2 in C++03):
"Each name that contains a double underscore (`__`) or begins with an 
underscore followed by an upper case letter is reserved for the
implementation for any use."  The standard is rather unclear as to what
happens if you violate this constraint, but traditionally, it has been
considered undefined behavior.